# How to Add labels & text box based on different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add labels & text box based on particular sheet.

I have created one user form where in its drop down I have written vba code to get sheet names inside the combo box now in particular sheet the sheet contains drawing number and various name of the parameters like diameter 1, length 1 etc & dimensions of the parts.

Now the user form which I am trying to make is to add the data on particular sheet (based on the selection of sheet in combo box). so that one has to not to go on each sheet and data manually.

I am not getting proper idea how to write vba code that add/reduces the labels & textbox based on the sheet name selection done in the combo box (means noob sheet contains Diameter1,Diameter2,length1, length2 while spring sheet contains numbers of turns, Diameter of wire, Compression length, Expansion Length etc) this are all varying list of parameters which I want to display in the Labels and In the textbox user will enter data and that data will particularly go into the particular sheet.
The user will select the sheet name in which he wants add data then all the list of parameters will be displayed in the labels and after selecting add button I will add to particular sheet.

pl. find in the attached images where I am showing my sheet & my user form.

If any body help me that how to do such thing through vba code it would be great help.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim A As Long
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    For A = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(A).Name
    Next
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Sheet name having spring data
[image: Sheet name having spring data]

Sheet Name Having noob data
[image: Sheet Name Having noob data]

[image: User form image]

Comment: Just call the contents of the cells containing the required names - then the form will have the names based on the sheet it is in.

Comment: @SolarMike but the caption inside the labels and the numbers of the labels and the textbox will not get vary as per the sheet means if sheet noob contains 4 labels and sheet spring contains 5 labels then number of labels and textbox  it will not vary as per the selection of the sheets

Comment: Then use the choose() function to get the correct names...

Comment: @SolarMike I am not able to do that means not having idea about that

Comment: @SolarMike Can you help me? in this if possible?

Comment: It's not practical to use a single userform for this, you should use a userform for each sheet or, if some sheets are similar, one userform for each set of similar sheets. You should also look into using listboxes instead of multiple labels/textboxes.

Comment: @norie May be you are right but the way I want to do that also might be possible to vary textbox ( I found in one of the YouTube video where one can add the number of textbox in the run time means you have to enter the number of textbox you want and that number of textbox comes in the user form) but I am not getting clear idea of syntax or how that's possible means how to co relate the number of textbox and labels based on sheet columns.

Comment: Sure you can dynamically add controls to a userform, but what about the code to handle the data? That would be different for each worksheet.

Comment: Have you considered using a [multipage-control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/multipage-control) ?

Comment: @norie through textbox i want to add data to the various sheet means it will find the last used row and through that it will add data below. Pl. let me know whether i am thinking correctly or not  P.S. "there are around 10 to 12 sheets only 2 of them i have shown here"

Comment: @CDP1802 nope i will look it whether it can help me in this or not thanks for the suggestion